# putting two cache evict on same method

Tags: spring, spring-cache

I have two cache on two methods . `brand` and `brands`

```
    @CacheEvict(value ={ "brand" }, key = "#brand.brandId")
    public Brand createOrUpdateBrand(final Brand brand){
    }


    @Cacheable("brands")
    public Set<String> getAllBrandNames()
    {
    }
```

Now i want to evict everything from `brands` when `createOrUpdateBrand` is called.

Can i do something like following ???

```
    @CacheEvict(value ={ "brand" }, key = "#brand.brandId")
    @CacheEvict("brands")
    public Brand createOrUpdateBrand(final Brand brand){
    }
```

OR

```
 @Caching(evict = { @CacheEvict("brands"), @CacheEvict(value = "brand", key = "#brand.brandId") })
```

Comment: From what I see on the way that @CacheEvict is declared it is impossible to put it twice on the same element (method in this case) - I am referring to your first suggestion

Comment: the last example sounds good except you are not giving any key to it. What do you want to evict from the `brands` cache?

Comment: well as u can see the getAllBrandNames() there is no key so i guess everything from brands cache

Comment: Well then you need to put the `allEntries` flag to `true`. Spring's not going to remove your entire cache region unless you explicitly ask for it! There's also a smell in your code as your are caching a set with an "null" key. It looks like you are using your cache as a data store.

Comment: Yes i am using cache as my data source. For null i am doing @Cacheable(value = "brand", key = "#brandId", unless = "#result == null") which will avoif storing null values. Would do you recommend..

Comment: Also i would like to know if there is a better way for brands cache because evicting all entries looks not good. Since there is no method parameter is there any way i can tell evict particlar value in cache only

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12036